# Change color of button with selector and remain this color

Tags: android, xml, drawable

That I want to do is change the color of the button if is press by the user. I need to states red/green. Button start be red, if you press change green and if you press again comeback to red. If press again, green....

I'm trying to find something similar but I can't find anything. 
Is possible to do it with a drawable selector?

This is that I'm trying and don't remain the color when finish the press

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- green state -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selector_green"
        android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <!-- green state -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selector_green"
        android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <!-- red state -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selecto_come_back"></item>

</selector>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When the button is pressed its state changes to "state_pressed".
However this does not happen for state_selected, if you want to use a Button and the selected state, you have to explicitly set the Button's state to selected via code, add an onClickListener to your button and inside onClick() do:

```
button.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
```

This will toggle the selected state every time the Button is pressed.

Comment: Hi Franesco, Is not possible to do it via selector drawable?

Comment: You can, but AFAIK not using a Button, try looking at ToggleButton and use the checked state instead. That should work. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Answer (score 0):

why you dont do that programaticaly?

just use a simple selector inside of the onClickListener

if(click=1)

button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);

else

button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);